# Create multi indexed dataframe by multipliying column value by another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Ok, so hopefully the title is understandable. I have two dataframes, one with datetime index and one column with values, and another with latitud and longitud and other columns.

The general layout is

```
df1=
                 factor
2015-04-15        NaN
2015-04-16        NaN
2015-04-17        NaN
2015-04-18        NaN
2015-04-19        NaN
2015-04-20        NaN
2015-04-21        NaN
2015-04-22        NaN
2015-04-23        NaN
2015-04-24   7.067218
2015-04-25   9.414628
2015-04-26  13.702154
2015-04-27  16.489926
2015-04-28  17.917428
2015-04-29  20.359118
2015-04-30  18.608707
2015-05-01  10.627798
2015-05-02   8.398942
2015-05-03   5.984976
2015-05-04   4.363621
2015-05-05   3.468062
2015-05-06   2.830794
2015-05-07   2.347879


df2=
      i_lat  i_lon       multiplier             sum   ID               distance
226   1092    264        -60.420166       61.420166  609  0.6142016587060164 km
228   1092    265       -129.914662      130.914662  609   1.309146617117938 km
204   1091    264       -203.371915      204.371915  609   2.043719152272311 km
206   1091    265       -233.799786      234.799786  609   2.347997860007727 km
224   1092    263       -240.718140      241.718140  609   2.417181399246371 km
..     ...    ...               ...             ...  ...                    ...
295   1095    268       -969.728516      970.728516  609   9.707285164114008 km
216   1092    259       -977.398084      978.398084  609   9.783980837220454 km
278   1094    269       -984.131470      985.131470  609   9.851314704203592 km
160   1088    267       -994.142285      995.142285  609   9.951422853836982 km
194   1091    259       -996.513606      997.513606  609   9.975136064824323 km
```

I basically need to do `df1["factor"]*df2["multiplier"]+df2["sum"]` for every pair of `i_lat and i_lon` so a multiindexed dataframe like this is outputed

```
df_output=
                                    col
i_lat    i_lon    time                             
1092    264   2015-04-15  -9.000000e+33
              2015-04-16  -9.000000e+33
              2015-04-17  -9.000000e+33
              2015-04-18  -9.000000e+33
              2015-04-19  -9.000000e+33
...                                         ...
1091    259   2015-05-05  -9.000000e+33
              2015-05-06  -9.000000e+33
              2015-05-07  -9.000000e+33
              2015-05-08  -9.000000e+33
              2015-05-09  -9.000000e+33
```

With `col` having the operation described above. I tried to use `apply`as `df2.apply(lambda a: print(df1*a["multiplier"]+a["sum"], axis=1))` but it returns something that doesnt make sense. Not really know how to continue from now on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df2=df2.set_index(['i_lat', 'i_lon'])

(pd.DataFrame(df1.values * df2.multiplier.values + df2['sum'].values, 
             index=df1.index,
             columns=df2.index
            )
   .unstack()
)
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I needed. Mind explaining the code a bit? Thanks!

Comment: the first part (`df1.values *...`) is basically `broadcasting` in numpy. The second part (`index=df1.index, columns=df2.index`) is label the data with correct name. Lastly, `unstack` is to turn a dataframe into a series with multiple index. You can read more on each keyword.

Comment: So it looks to have the structure i need it to have but it says its a `Series` and not a `DataFrame`. How can I keep the structure and make it a dataframe?

Comment: chain it with `.to_frame(name='col_name')` and you will get a dataframe.